# Iterate through generic class

Tags: java, android, reflection, iteration

Is there anyway possible to print out the name, and type of every field in a class? Right now I have the following code

```
try {
   for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
   System.out.println("User Preferences " + field.getName()
                     + " - " + field.getType());
   }
}catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which displays:

```
User Preferences customer - class java.lang.String
User Preferences token - class java.lang.String
User Preferences class1 - class com.activity.webservice.Login$Class1
```

That is what I want to get (almost).

The issue is getting it to go into the custom class Class1. The Class1 class can have multiple classes within it or no classes. The Class1 class can have multiple fields or no fields.

I want something like this to print out

```
User Preferences customer - class java.lang.String
User Preferences token - class java.lang.String
User Preferences class1 - class com.activity.webservice.Login$Class1
User Preferences string1 - class java.lang.String
User Preferences class2 - class com.activity.webservice.Login$Class2
User Preferences string2 - class java.lang.String
User Preferences string3 - class java.lang.String
```

How can I iterate through an unknown number of fields and classes?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

Here is how my Login class is structured

```
public class Login {

     public String token;   
     public String customerid;
     public Class1 class1;

     public class Class1 {
            public Class2 class2;
            public String string1;

            public class Class2 {
                    public int int1;
                    public String string2;
                    public String string3;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: What data structure holds this information?

Comment: @m0skit0 this would be a method in its own class. Whatever object I pass in I can get the info I need

Comment: Use recursive method - each level getting into the member class

Comment: @Bhaskar how would I pass in the new class to iterate through? Would I make obj = Class1 and then call my method again. Stop the method when I don't see another class?

Comment: you would pass the Class<> of the member field into the recursive call and stop if the current Class token has no fields inside it ie its a primitive one. ( or come up with your own custom logic of when to stop searching further down )

Comment: @Bhaskar thanks. Could you show me a small example so I can accept the answer.

Comment: Just like you have shown what the output be like, can you show us for exactly what input the output be that?

Comment: @BigT, kcoppock has pretty much nailed it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general idea of how you would do this recursively. Just pass in the class that you want the fields for, and it should recursively check the fields of all subclasses as well.

```
// Call this method to get the list of fields.
public static List<String> getAllFields(Class<?> clazz) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    getFieldDescsForClass(clazz, results);
    return results;
}

private static void getFieldDescsForClass(Class<?> clazz, List<String> outList) {
    // Loop over all the fields and add the info for each field
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        // Ignore synthetic fields
        if (!field.isSynthetic()) {
            outList.add(String.format("User Preferences %s - %s", field.getName(), field.getType()));
        }
    }

    // For any internal classes, recursively call this method and add the results
    // (which will in turn do this for all of that subclass's subclasses)
    for (Class subclazz : clazz.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        getFieldDescsForClass(subclazz, outList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oops, I just misunderstood the question. Sorry!

Comment: @kcoppock check the edit I made above. This method goes into Class1 but returns a random long variable. Would this method work with my structure?

Comment: A random long? Is your class serializable? It could be returning the serial ID. This should certainly work with your class structure; are you not seeing it work recursively?

Comment: @kcoppock it is serializable. I was passing an object not a class. This works great. My output is showing this$0 For Login and this$1 for Class1. Is there a way not to show that?

Comment: Those are implicit references to the outer class (since the inner classes are non-static). You can avoid catching these by checking `field.isSynthetic()` before adding to the list. If `isSynthetic()` is true, it's an implicitly added field.

Comment: @kcoppock how would I get the value of the field? I can get the name but when I get the value I get a IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
static List structure = new ArrayList();

static void getClassStructure(Class clazz, List structure){
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f : fields){
        structure.add(f.getType());
    }

    Class[] classes = clazz.getDeclaredClasses();
    for(Class c : classes){
        getClassStructure(c, structure);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class clazz = new Login().getClass();
    getClassStructure(clazz, structure);
    System.out.println(structure);

}
```

}

Tested it on

```
class Login {

public String token;   
public String customerid;
public Class1 class1;

public class Class1 {
       public Class2 class2;
       public String string1;

       public class Class2 {
               public int int1;
               public String string2;
               public String string3;
       }
}
```

}

Output :

class java.lang.String

class java.lang.String

class Login$Class1

class Login$Class1$Class2

class java.lang.String

class Login

int

class java.lang.String

class java.lang.String

class Login$Class1